# MPI using message tag to put the values in right order

Tags: c++, mpi, communication

I wrote little program where I am sending some random values placed in array from my master proces to slaves. Slaves are counting little equation, and they should send back the result to master. Now master should place the results to new results array in right order. Im using message tag.
Here are the methods:

Sending one element of my task list to slaves

```
void Ccalculation::masterSend(int * tasklist)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < this->world_size; i++) {
        MPI_Send(&tasklist[current], 1, MPI_INT, i, current, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        current++;
    }
}
```

Receiving task from master by slave

```
void Ccalculation::slaceRecv()
{

    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Recv(&slaveTask, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    //here I am creating variable whith tag which I ll be returning
    msgTag = status.MPI_TAG;
    cout << "msg tag: " << status.MPI_TAG << " number " << slaveTask << endl;
}
```

Here the problem begins

Sending solution to master whith specific tag

```
void Ccalculation::slaveSend(double solution)
{
        MPI_Send(&solution, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, msgTag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
```

Receiving solution by master and putting it to solutionArray

```
void Ccalculation::masterRecv(double *solutionTab)
{
    double buffer = 0;
    MPI_Status status;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < this->world_size; i++)
    {
        MPI_Recv(&buffer, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        solutionTab[status.MPI_TAG] = buffer;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue when you run your code? Are you initializing `current = 0` in `masterSend`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MPI is built-in functions to solve problems like this. They are refered to as **collective operations**. In particular, to distribute - as you call it - elements from your task list to different processes, you can use [MPI_Scatter](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Scatter.3.php). The reverse operation of collecting one element from each process is realized by [MPI_gather](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Gather.3.php).

You can replace both your `masterSend` and `slaceRecv` functions by just one line of code:

```
MPI_Scatter(tasklist, this->world_size, MPI_INT, &current, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Analogously, you can replace your functions `slaveSend` and `masterRecv` with just one line of code, using `MPI_Gather`.

Comment: In my project I had to use only MPI_Send and MPI_Recv functions, problem solved but thank You so much :)